# TestLink APIException with Status Code issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testlink

While using the TestLink APIConst values below, the xml-rpc call produced an Exception. No report was printed for the corresponding Test case

```
testlinkResult = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_DEPARTED;
testlinkResult = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_WRONG;
```

calling reportTCResult() with either of those status codes produced the following Exceptions

```
The xml-rpc call to TestLink API method tl.reportTCResult failed.
Result[0] = {message=The status code (d) provided is not valid!, code=6000}
The xml-rpc call to TestLink API method tl.reportTCResult failed.
Result[0] = {message=The status code (w) provided is not valid!, code=6000}
```

when i used `TEST_PASSED`,`TEST_FAILED`, results were printed successfully.  My question is why do the `TEST_DEPARTED` and `TEST_WRONG` fail?

---

Testing Framework : TestNG with Selenum Webdriver & Java

let me know if any changes or information about config files etc are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help of Richard, need to update the following files in Testlink

```
cfg/const.inc.php
```

in the above file will update the following

```
$tlCfg->results['status_label']
$tlCfg->results['status_label_for_exec_ui']
$tlCfg->results['charts']['status_colour']
```

add all the newly introduced status should be added

```
locale/en_gb /string.txt
 Status (used wide)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the Testlink server API is very hard to find!  However, I did a bit of searching and found some auto generated documentation on [someones blog here](http://www.jetmore.org/john/blog/2012/02/testlink-1-9-3-api-documentation/), which led me to [this question](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19369?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) (with regard to integrating Testlink with Jenkins)

The result is that it seems on your testlink server, you need to set up the status codes you want to use. Looking at the testlink server [code here](https://gitorious.org/testlink-ga/testlink-ga/source/e8435ae81e886fc22663ca29a1b82ef4a0d3572b:cfg/const.inc.php) it seems they are set up in the `const.inc.php` file (line 420 in the version posted there).  The default appears to be:

```
$tlCfg->results['status_code'] = array (
'failed' => 'f',
'blocked' => 'b',
'passed' => 'p',
'not_run' => 'n',
'not_available' => 'x',
'unknown' => 'u',
'all' => 'a'
);
```

One way to do this is to add the statuses you want to use directly to that file.  If you already have something called `custom_config.inc.php` or similar in your installation - you might have to add the array there instead - see [this question in the testlink bug tracker](http://forum.testlink.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1161).

You need to add

```
'departed` => 'd'
```

and

```
'wrong' => 'w'
```

so your array now looks like:

```
$tlCfg->results['status_code'] = array (
'failed' => 'f',
'blocked' => 'b',
'passed' => 'p',
'not_run' => 'n',
'not_available' => 'x',
'unknown' => 'u',
'all' => 'a',
'departed' => 'd',
'wrong' => 'w'
);
```

Don't forget the commas, or you might run [into this problem](http://forum.testlink.org/viewtopic.php?p=3835#p3835) (reported on the Testlink bug system)

Comment: @Richard: Thanks , let you know once got an positive output

Comment: No problem - hope it works (I haven't a Testlink server to try it on at the moment, used to use it...)